# Google translate service not available on Translation Management module(Drupal 6)

Tags: i18n-l10n

When I using the translation management to translate my node, I got "Google translation failed to Chinese, Simplified: Google returned error #403: Quota Exceeded. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html", anyone know what happen and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like is said on that page http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html access to Google Translate API is now limited.

If you still want continue to use the module you should have a look into this discussion http://drupal.org/node/1215426 where they are looking for another solution.